# SQL query to find data that doesn't meet a threshold

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find a list of value combinations that will identify opportunities as combinations that don't exist.  The data I have looks like this.

| Company | Product |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 3 |
| D | 1 |
| E | 2 |
| E | 4 |

I want to identify products that at least 3 companies sell then tell the companies that aren't selling what products are popular.  For this example, products 1 and 2 are sold by at least 3 companies.  Product 1 is not being sold by companies B and E, and product 2 is not being sold by companies C and D.  The query results would look like.

| Company | Product |
| --- | --- |
| B | 1 |
| E | 1 |
| C | 2 |
| D | 2 |

Oracle is the database, and the actual number of rows is ~ 1M.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aggregate and use a `HAVING` clause to find the products that meet the threshold and then use a `PARTITION`ed `OUTER JOIN` to find the non-matching rows:

```sql
SELECT t.company, p.product
FROM   ( SELECT product
         FROM   table_name
         GROUP BY product
         HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Company) >= 3) p
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table_name t
       PARTITION BY (t.company)
       ON (p.product = t.product)
WHERE  t.product IS NULL
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Company, Product) AS
SELECT 'A', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E', 4 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | COMPANY | PRODUCT |
> | --- | --- |
> | B | 1 |
> | C | 2 |
> | D | 2 |
> | E | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fd97acba58c806c4067727287c2baf49)*